# Get the "latest" datetime from a large linq query that currently returns every record that has a datetime

Tags: c#, .net, linq, group-by, inner-join

I have a fairly long linq query and everything works as it should..  but in a final join i am doing an innerjoin on a table that has a log, the log returns more than 50 records, i just want the latest record..

Here is an example

```
var tst = from w in context.storage
          join p in context.products on w.id equals p.wid
          join l in context.logger on p.id equals l.pid
          select new
          {
              storageid = w.id,
              productid = p.id
              productname = p.name
              bought = l.when
          };
```

So a quick explanation of what happens, each product is stored in a storage center and there is a log when that product was bought, if it was bought 100 times then there is 100 records in the logger.

So currently it returns 50 records for productid = 5 ... why .. because it was bought 50 times but i only want 1 record,  hence i only want the latest date time for from the logger.

Can anyone help? I am a little stuck.

Comment: Is this LINQ to SQL or Entity Framework?

Comment: is there a field in the db that stores datetime when record is submited

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `result.Distinct(x => x.Prop)` to get unique entries only

Use `result.Max(x => x.Prop)` to get latest date, and `Min()` to get earliest.

Answer (score 1):

This is a case where you want to restrict to collection of records on which to join, which you can do by coding the join manually (sort of):

```
from w in context.storage
join p in context.products on w.id equals p.wid
// "manual" join:
from l in context.logger.Where(l => l.pid == p.id).OrderByDescencing(l => l.when).Take(1)
select new
{
    storageid = w.id,
    productid = p.id
    productname = p.name
    bought = l.when
};
```

In fluent linq syntax this is a [SelectMany with a result selector](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549040).